# Unresolved external symbol error when using xtensor for linear algebra

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, xtensor

I'm trying to use xtensor (in Visual Studio) to find the eigenvalues of an xarray using `linalg::eigvals()` in `xtensor`. Below is a simple program I'm trying to make work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xmath.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xcomplex.hpp"
#include "xtensor-blas/xlinalg.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace xt;
int main()
{
    auto test = empty<double>({ 5,5 });
    auto test1 = ones_like(test);
    xarray<complex<double>> eig = linalg::eigvals(test1);
    return 0;
}
```

It works down until the `xarray<>` line.

But when it gets to that line, I get the error:

```
FileName.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dgeev_ referenced in function "int __cdecl 
cxxlapack::geev<int>(char,char,int,double *,int,double *,double *,double *,int,double *,int,double 
*,int)" (??$geev@H@cxxlapack@@YAHDDHPANH000H0H0H@Z)
```

I have already tried the `Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library dependencies` and added `C:\...\Debug\FileName.obj` which gave the same error.

Comment: Looks like you are calling a function that does not match the definition of the external function you are linking to. Is there more code?

Comment: There isn't any more code in the cpp file. I specifically made this small sample to isolate the problem, which lies in the xarray<> line. If I comment that line out the code runs.

Comment: I think you were close with trying to add `C:\...\Debug\FileName.obj` to your linker includes. Try finding the file `FileName.lib` and add that. As a note, `.obj` files are not needed in the linker includes; they're an intermediate compilation file that get generated on build. `.lib` files contain the function definitions, which are especially important when using cross-language libraries, such as xtensor with c++

Comment: Have you linked against LAPACK lib? If you are building your project with CMake, you need to find LAPACK and then link with target_link_libraries(targetpro ${BLAS_LIBRARIES} ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}). Probably, you d need to share your CMake file as well.

Comment: Like @GioR says, it seems that you are not linking to LAPACK. How do you compile?

Comment: I'll try to look into how I do that. Those things are beyond what I know right now (as is the 'how do you compile' question, unless just saying that I use the Local Windows Debugger on VS is an answer).

Comment: OK. Searching a bit on the internet to linking (blas) on Windows should eventually help you to find the right setup (and teach you what linking means). Sorry, I’m not on Windows, so I cannot really help you.